# GCC not added to system path on pacman install

Tags: linux, gcc, mingw, archlinux, msys2

### Issue

When installing mingw on a fresh [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) instance I run into the issue of gcc not found:

```
$ g++
bash: g++: command not found
```

### Setup

Fresh MSYS2 install on relatively clean windows 10 install:

```
pacman -Syu 
pacman -Su 
pacman -S make 
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

### Diagnostics

It appears that GCC is successfully installed into the directory `/mingw64/bin`

Yet my path consists of

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:
```

As such gcc is not found.

I have tried adding `/mingw64/bin` to the `$PATH` however this seems like a temporary fix of an underlying problem.

---

My question specifically is, is there any reason as to why either the mingw is not installed into the `/usr/bin/` directory or the installation did not add itself to the path, and or any simple reason as to what is causing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you installed `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` it seems like you want to compile 64-bit native Windows applications.  Therefore, you should start MSYS2 by running `mingw64.exe`, found at the top level of your MSYS2 installation.  That will put `/mingw64/bin/` on your PATH and set some other useful environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

I have found simply adding `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the host windows computers `PATH` variable this, in turn, adds `\mingw64\bin` to the MSYS2 `$PATH` solving the problem.